# Fascinating! The buzzing bridge in Lisbon

Tags: field-recording, city, traffic, documentation

Hello group! May be one of you has once already heard this intense buzzing sound coming from this bridge. I hope you like the audiovisual stuff I posted in FB. http://www.facebook.com/yoursounds On SoundCloud you may listen as well. Regards, Eckhard Kuchenbecker

Comment: @Eckhard K, thanks for posting! I'd not heard of this before. Also, don't know who gave you the down vote but it was unwarranted. 

Comment: @Eckhard K, if given the opportunity you should attach some contact mics to the supports, and perhaps a hydrophone near the base.

Comment: Hi Jay! Thank you and yesss! contact mics will be part of my gear for my next travel to Lisbon. I did not think about hydrophones before, but why not? By the way, have you seen this: http://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.239451376074550.66118.125174460835576&type=3 ? Best hydrophones I know.